# how doesn't 'while(temp)' work and 'while(temp.next)' does?

Tags: python, loops, class, methods, linked-list

I don't understand why in line 31 of my code, it needs to be `while(temp.next):` instead of  `while(temp):`Can someone please help me understand? I am new and confused. Here is my code for my Linked List:

```
class Node():
     def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def printlist(self):
        temp = self.head
        while(temp):
            print(temp.data)
            temp = temp.next

    def append(self, new_data):
        new_node = Node(new_data)
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = new_node
        else:
            temp = self.head

            #if I replace the following line with "while(temp):" instead of 
            #"while(temp.next)"it will not work. Why?

            while(temp.next):
                temp = temp.next
            temp.next = new_node

 


mylist = LinkedList()
mylist.head = Node(1)
mylist.append(2)
mylist.printlist()
```

Comment: `while (temp)` stops when `temp` becomes `None`.  Once it stops looping and executes `temp.next = new_node`, what do you expect will happen?

Comment: Did you try to [trace what the code does](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) when you do it the other way? "it will not work. Why?" Well, first off, think about what "will not work" **means**. What is the wrong thing that happens? How do you know it is wrong? What should happen instead?

Comment: Hint: when the `while(temp.next)` condition is not met, what is `temp.next` equal to? If you use `while(temp)` instead, when that condition is not met, what would `temp` be equal to? What is the next thing the code tries to do with `temp` after the loop? If `temp` has that value, would it make sense to try to do that? Why or why not? (Deeper hint: in your own words, what is `None` in Python?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while (temp)` will ensure that `temp` is falsy (`None`) when the loop *exits*. But then the statement below that loop will fail:

```
        temp.next = new_node
```

...as there is no `next` attribute when `temp` is `None`.

The goal of this `while` loop is to find the *last* node. The distinguishing characteristic of the last node is that its `next` attribute is `None`, so that explains the `while` condition. As long as this node still has a successor, it is not the last node, and we should step forward. That is what this loop is doing.